# CodeBlocks HelloWorld C example not working: error "ptrdiff_t" not been declared

Tags: c++, codeblocks

I've always used MinGW or Dev-C++ to write code in C++ on Microsoft Windows, but now I have to use Code Blocks.
I've downloaded it and installed it, with the standard procedure.

I've tried to run the supersimple HelloWorld.cpp example file, but I got many compiling errors:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
  cout << “Hello World!” << endl;
}
```

Here's the list of my compiler errors:

```
Compiling: C:\Temp7\provaC\test00.cpp
In file included from C:/Dev-Cpp/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/3.4.2/../../../../include/c++/3.4.2/cstring:49,
                 from C:/Dev-Cpp/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/3.4.2/../../../../include/c++/3.4.2/mingw32/bits/c++locale.h:42,
                 from C:/Dev-Cpp/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/3.4.2/../../../../include/c++/3.4.2/iosfwd:46,
                 from C:/Dev-Cpp/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/3.4.2/../../../../include/c++/3.4.2/ios:44,
                 from C:/Dev-Cpp/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/3.4.2/../../../../include/c++/3.4.2/ostream:45,
                 from C:/Dev-Cpp/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/3.4.2/../../../../include/c++/3.4.2/iostream:45,
                 from C:\Temp7\provaC\test00.cpp:1:
C:/Dev-Cpp/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/3.4.2/../../../../include/c++/3.4.2/cstddef:52: error: `::ptrdiff_t' has not been declared
C:/Dev-Cpp/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/3.4.2/../../../../include/c++/3.4.2/cstddef:53: error: `::size_t' has not been declared
In file included from C:/Dev-Cpp/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/3.4.2/../../../../include/c++/3.4.2/cstring:51,
                 from C:/Dev-Cpp/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/3.4.2/../../../../include/c++/3.4.2/mingw32/bits/c++locale.h:42,
                 from C:/Dev-Cpp/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/3.4.2/../../../../include/c++/3.4.2/iosfwd:46,
                 from C:/Dev-Cpp/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/3.4.2/../../../../include/c++/3.4.2/ios:44,
                 from C:/Dev-Cpp/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/3.4.2/../../../../include/c++/3.4.2/ostream:45,
                 from C:/Dev-Cpp/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/3.4.2/../../../../include/c++/3.4.2/iostream:45,
                 from C:\Temp7\provaC\test00.cpp:1:
C:/Dev-Cpp/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/3.4.2/../../../../include/string.h:36: error: `size_t' has not been declared
C:/Dev-Cpp/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/3.4.2/../../../../include/string.h:37: error: `size_t' has not been declared
C:/Dev-Cpp/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/3.4.2/../../../../include/string.h:38: error: `size_t' has not been declared
C:/Dev-Cpp/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/3.4.2/../../../../include/string.h:39: error: `size_t' has not been declared
C:/Dev-Cpp/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/3.4.2/../../../../include/string.h:40: error: `size_t' has not been declared
C:/Dev-Cpp/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/3.4.2/../../../../include/string.h:46: error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before "strcspn"
C:/Dev-Cpp/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/3.4.2/../../../../include/string.h:46: error: expected `,' or `;' before "strcspn"
C:/Dev-Cpp/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/3.4.2/../../../../include/string.h:49: error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before "strlen"
C:/Dev-Cpp/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/3.4.2/../../../../include/string.h:49: error: expected `,' or `;' before "strlen"
C:/Dev-Cpp/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/3.4.2/../../../../include/string.h:50: error: `size_t' has not been declared
C:/Dev-Cpp/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/3.4.2/../../../../include/string.h:51: error: `size_t' has not been declared
C:/Dev-Cpp/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/3.4.2/../../../../include/string.h:52: error: `size_t' has not been declared
C:/Dev-Cpp/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/3.4.2/../../../../include/string.h:55: error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before "strspn"
C:/Dev-Cpp/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/3.4.2/../../../../include/string.h:55: error: expected `,' or `;' before "strspn"
C:/Dev-Cpp/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/3.4.2/../../../../include/string.h:58: error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before "strxfrm"
C:/Dev-Cpp/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/3.4.2/../../../../include/string.h:58: error: expected `,' or `;' before "strxfrm"
C:/Dev-Cpp/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/3.4.2/../../../../include/string.h:65: error: `size_t' has not been declared
C:/Dev-Cpp/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/3.4.2/../../../../include/string.h:66: error: `size_t' has not been declared
C:/Dev-Cpp/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/3.4.2/../../../../include/string.h:72: error: `size_t' has not been declared
C:/Dev-Cpp/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/3.4.2/../../../../include/string.h:73: error: `size_t' has not been declared
C:/Dev-Cpp/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/3.4.2/../../../../include/string.h:77: error: `size_t' has not been declared
C:/Dev-Cpp/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/3.4.2/../../../../include/string.h:80: error: `size_t' has not been declared
C:/Dev-Cpp/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/3.4.2/../../../../include/string.h:81: error: `size_t' has not been declared
C:/Dev-Cpp/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/3.4.2/../../../../include/string.h:90: error: `size_t' has not been declared
C:/Dev-Cpp/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/3.4.2/../../../../include/string.h:91: error: `size_t' has not been declared
C:/Dev-Cpp/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/3.4.2/../../../../include/string.h:100: error: `size_t' has not been declared
C:/Dev-Cpp/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/3.4.2/../../../../include/string.h:102: error: `size_t' has not been declared
C:/Dev-Cpp/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/3.4.2/../../../../include/string.h:104: error: `size_t' has not been declared
C:/Dev-Cpp/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/3.4.2/../../../../include/string.h:109: error: `size_t' has not been declared
C:/Dev-Cpp/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/3.4.2/../../../../include/string.h:125: error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before "wcscspn"
C:/Dev-Cpp/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/3.4.2/../../../../include/string.h:125: error: expected `,' or `;' before "wcscspn"
C:/Dev-Cpp/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/3.4.2/../../../../include/string.h:127: error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before "wcslen"
C:/Dev-Cpp/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/3.4.2/../../../../include/string.h:127: error: expected `,' or `;' before "wcslen"
C:/Dev-Cpp/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/3.4.2/../../../../include/string.h:128: error: `size_t' has not been declared
C:/Dev-Cpp/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/3.4.2/../../../../include/string.h:129: error: `size_t' has not been declared
C:/Dev-Cpp/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/3.4.2/../../../../include/string.h:130: error: `size_t' has not been declared
C:/Dev-Cpp/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/3.4.2/../../../../include/string.h:133: error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before "wcsspn"
C:/Dev-Cpp/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/3.4.2/../../../../include/string.h:133: error: expected `,' or `;' before "wcsspn"
C:/Dev-Cpp/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/3.4.2/../../../../include/string.h:136: error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before "wcsxfrm"
C:/Dev-Cpp/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/3.4.2/../../../../include/string.h:136: error: expected `,' or `;' before "wcsxfrm"
C:/Dev-Cpp/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/3.4.2/../../../../include/string.h:150: error: `size_t' has not been declared
C:/Dev-Cpp/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/3.4.2/../../../../include/string.h:151: error: `size_t' has not been declared
C:/Dev-Cpp/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/3.4.2/../../../../include/string.h:157: error: `size_t' has not been declared
C:/Dev-Cpp/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/3.4.2/../../../../include/string.h:158: error: `size_t' has not been declared
C:/Dev-Cpp/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/3.4.2/../../../../include/string.h:175: error: `size_t' has not been declared
C:/Dev-Cpp/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/3.4.2/../../../../include/string.h:176: error: `size_t' has not been declared
In file included from C:/Dev-Cpp/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/3.4.2/../../../../include/c++/3.4.2/mingw32/bits/c++locale.h:42,
                 from C:/Dev-Cpp/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/3.4.2/../../../../include/c++/3.4.2/iosfwd:46,
                 from C:/Dev-Cpp/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/3.4.2/../../../../include/c++/3.4.2/ios:44,
                 from C:/Dev-Cpp/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/3.4.2/../../../../include/c++/3.4.2/ostream:45,
                 from C:/Dev-Cpp/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/3.4.2/../../../../include/c++/3.4.2/iostream:45,
                 from C:\Temp7\provaC\test00.cpp:1:
C:/Dev-Cpp/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/3.4.2/../../../../include/c++/3.4.2/cstring:89: error: `::strxfrm' has not been declared
C:/Dev-Cpp/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/3.4.2/../../../../include/c++/3.4.2/cstring:90: error: `::strcspn' has not been declared
Process terminated with status 1 (0 minutes, 5 seconds)
```

It seems that in the standard libraries some structures are absent (`ptr_diff_t`, `size_t`, etc).

Could someone help me and let me compile my simple HelloWorld.cpp?

Thanks!

Comment: The necessary includes for your program are `<ostream>` and `<iostream>`.

Comment: @Kerrek SB, see http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/; I believe you normally wouldn't need istream or ostream to be directly included as they're both covered by iostream. I don't know what the problem is here as this works fine with Eclipse and MinGW. I'm guessing it's a configuration issue. Can you get the command line used for the compilation and try it from a Command Prompt?

Comment: @cosimo193: That website is an abomination. However, I think you're (unwittingly) right that C++11 *does* mandate that `<iostream>` include `<ostream>`; C++03 did not say this.

Comment: @KerrekSB by mowing this output to the right you'll see that **ostream** is included from **iostream** in this very case.

Answer (score 0):

It's your quotation marks which are causing the problem:

See how `“”` is different from `""`? That's why it is not compiling. They are not valid characters in C++.

Answer (score 0):

You are using wrong quotation marks.. Change `“` and `”` to `""`